# Python 3 Quicksort Implementation Not Working

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, quicksort

I Am Running A Test Script to do Quicksort On List Since there are so many ways for partitioning in quicksort and selection of pivot element

i am using here selecting the first index of list as pivot
`pivot=list[0]`
and then do sorting `pivot_pos=quicksort(list,l,h)`

l:Lower Bound & h:Higher/Upper Bound

after returning appropriate index of pivot the list is break into two parts
such that:

`LEFT PART`:`quicksort(list,l,pivot_pos-1)`&

`RIGHT PART`:`quicksort(list,pivot_pos+1,h)`

Since the location of pivot is returned we not include him in next recursion call

The `quicksort`function do partitioning in quick while `partition` function return index that belong to pivot element.

The Full Code Is Below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# quicksort by selecting first element as pivot

def partition(list,l,h):
 pivot=list[l]
 i=l
 j=h

 while(i<=j):
  if list[i]<pivot:
   i+=1
  if list[j]>pivot:
   j-=1
  if (list[i]> pivot and list[j]<pivot):
   list[i],list[j]=list[j],list[i]

 list[j],pivot=pivot,list[j]
 return j

def quicksort(list,l,h):
 if l<h:
  pivot_pos=partition(list,l,h)
  quicksort(list,l,pivot_pos-1)
  quicksort(list,pivot_pos+1,h)



def main():
 list=[] # empty list
 # creating a user defined list
 n=int(input('Define length of array:'))
 for a in range(0,n):
  x=int(input('list{}='.format(a)))
  list.append(x)
 l=0
 h=int(len(list)-1)
 print("l:",l)
 print("h:",h)
 print('Before Sorting:',list)
 quicksort(list,l,h)
 print('After Sorting:',list)

main()
```

this is good approach of writing quicksort as this not involve too many loop bringing the time complexity to as low as could with this setup

but the code is not working ahead its just stuck
you can see o/p here[o/p_of_code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qux1U.png)

For Those Who Are Unfamiliar With Quicksort [Read-It here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/)

Comment: The Approach Is Good But The Implemenation Does Not Giving Any O/p Any Suggestionn to Code & improvement is appreciated

Comment: As an aside, never use `list` as a variable name in Python, since doing so masks the builtin.  This has nothing to do with your problem, but it's something to avoid.

Comment: @TomKarzes K I Would Consider this next tym but do you got any solution of this?

Comment: Ok, I posted a solution.  Give it a try, it should work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `parition` with the following:

```
def partition(lst,l,h):
 pivot=lst[l]
 i=h
 for j in range(h, l, -1):
  if lst[j] > pivot:
   lst[i],lst[j]=lst[j],lst[i]
   i-=1
 lst[i],lst[l]=lst[l],lst[i]
 return i
```

Note:  I completely rewrote this answer.  The original answer I posted wasn't right.  This is a more standard solution, and I've tested it and it handles all my test cases.  This version uses the first element as the pivot.

Comment: @TomKazes Thnx but at the end you are not swaping pivot element to its index i in lst list

Comment: @TomKazes i Am not getting it as i and j refrence only swapping values which are lesser and greater than pivot and once the ith index  crosses j that index is pivot_postiion now without changing new location of pivot how we are determining the sub array's

Comment: @TomKazes It won't once the pivot index is returned the next recurssion followed from (l,pivot_pos-1)&(pivot_pos+1,h)so the next call doesn't contained previous pivot element

Comment: @TomKazes I Am agree with You its working great but i am saying from algorithm perspective that we swap pivot only when i crosses j and then swaping pivot element and in the next recursion call we make sure this tym previous pivot not participate although your solution is good and i appreciate it thnx

Comment: @TomKazes That's a Very Intiutional Answer Of Solution appreciate it & i see you edit to answer Thnx

Comment: @TomKazes Sorry tom but this is selecting pivot as last element not the first element as i mentioned above the last element as pivot is simplest and i already solve it i am looking for selcting pivot as begining of list and then do quicksort as mentioned in the quicksort link there are 4 ways to selecting pivot and selecting from begining is one of them

Comment: @CoderWithDIfficulties Ok, I updated it with a version that uses `lst[l]` as the pivot value.  Refresh your page and take a look.  I just needed to reverse everything from what I had previously.  Sorry it took so long.  Anyway, let me know if you have any questions about it.